# Looking for a data-set of server performance data

Tags: machine-learning, visualization

I am looking for a data-set of server performance stats collected from one of more servers. Does anyone know where I could find or if someone can provide a data set - the project is to test some interesting visualisations and some predictive functions.

So far I have looked on

- AWS Public data sets
- Numerous GitHub posts which have URLs for Data-sets
- Kaggle
- UCI
- Stanford Data-set collections page
- R-Dir
- Reddit
- Crawdad

None of them have any data-sets which have anything close, so if anyone can donate a data-set or point me to a resource I have missed I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

**What info would you like?** I would be happy to send you the data you are looking for, but, need a general direction of what specific measures you are looking at having.

In the meantime, here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jdwall/f196b09f4edce308ad3321f58f4637b0) of performance data from three boxes - php5, php7 and media server.

- `cpu.usage.average` - CPU usage as a percentage during the interval
- `cpu.usagemhz.average` - CPU usage in megahertz during the interval
- `mem.usage.average` - Memory usage as percentage of total configured
  or available memory
- `disk.usage.average` - Aggregated disk I/O rate.
  For hosts, this metric includes the rates for all virtual machines
  running on the host during the collection interval.
- `net.usage.average` - Network utilization (combined transmit-rates
  and receive-rates) during the interval
- `sys.uptime.latest` - Total
  time elapsed, in seconds, since last system startup

[image: cpu mhz example]